# Analytic formula for parameterizing the below family of curves

Tags: graphing-functions, parametrization

I'm trying to find an analytic formula for a curve that can look like any of the curves below depending on one or more parameters. My initial thought was to use exponentials, something that might include functions like $1-e^{-x}$ or $e^x-1$, but I don't think this quite works to capture most or all of the curves below. I'd preferably like something of the form y=f(x), being a single variable function rather than using a parametric equation. [image]

Comment: $x^n$, for any positive $n$.

Comment: @Chappers Can you post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $y=x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is a positive real number, will do this: $\alpha = 1$ is the diagonal, as $\alpha \to 0$, the line approaches the left and top sides of the square, and reflecting in $y=x$ gives $y=x^{1/\alpha}$, which also corresponds to the cases with $\alpha<1$.